# How do I restart Apache on Windows?  "Apache -k restart" gives error "No installed service named "Apache2"

Tags: windows, apache-2.2

Apache is currently running. Some solutions offered elsewhere on the Internet suggest typing `apache -k install` and then retrying `apache -k restart`.  But if I try that, I get another error,

> Only one usage of each socket is permitted.

`apache -k stop` gives the following error (the same as I originally got from `apache -k restart`),

> No installed service named "Apache2"

Answer (score 11):

There is a small application Apache installs, usually displayed in the [system tray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar#Taskbar_elements) from where you can restart Apache.

You can restart a service with many utilities, like `sc.exe`, but just using the shell, use

```
net stop Apache2.2-Zend && net start Apache2.2-Zend
```

In my case, the name of the service is `Apache2.2-Zend`. You can check the name in `services.msc`.

Comment: I've using Certbot for automatic renewal, but it never worked. It used "Apache2.4" as default name, but thanks to your hint to check the service name I could fix it!

Answer (score 6):

First you must bring the command prompt to the `bin` of Apache folder on your computer, i.e my Apache folder is in directory `C:\Apache24\`.
I used command `cd C:\Apache24\bin` and then used command `httpd -k restart` to restart the Apache service.

Answer (score 2):

I found another way.  Using the Windows GUI, I selected Start->Programs->Administrative Tools->Services.  I then searched for Apache in the running services.  I did not find it.  I found one called sugarApache however.  I was able to restart the sugarApache using the 'Services' GUI.

Answer (score -2):

For Windows Server 2008, after an automatically downloaded update and server reset our Apache server stopped. Error logs read as follows:

> The Apache service named reported access a socket in a way forbidden by
>   its access permissions.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   Logged 12/10/2016 9:04:13 AM (the time the server downloaded and reset a
>   Windows update)

Also:

> The Apache service named reported the following error: no listening
>   sockets available, shutting down.
>   The Apache service named  reported the following error: unable to open logs.

The way to fix this (because simple restart doesn't work) is to open a command prompt and type:

```
iireset/stop
```

Thereafter restart Apache by running:

```
services.msc
```

Pick Apache, and hit start.

Or you can pick any other way you want to restart Apache.